# Spring Hello World Web App

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying out Spring Framework for a web app and can't seem to have it work with a simple hello world MVC web app.  Using Spring 3.2, Tomcat 6 (context set as "/spring").  Maybe the annotated Controller class is not found?

I am hitting `http://localhost:8080/spring/hello`

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" > 
    <display-name>
      Spring
    </display-name>
    <description>
     Spring Test
    </description>

     <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

springapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.web" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My Controller

```
package com.test.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Test");
        return "hello";
    }


}
```

Tomcat Output (springapp-servlet.xml is found and loaded)

```
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor spring.xml
Jan 20, 2013 10:22:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springapp'
Jan 20, 2013 10:22:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springapp': initialization started
Jan 20, 2013 10:22:27 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springapp-servlet': startup date [Sun Jan 20 22:22:27 EST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 20, 2013 10:22:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml]
Jan 20, 2013 10:22:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7897aaa6: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Jan 20, 2013 10:22:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'springapp': initialization completed in 321 ms
Jan 20, 2013 10:22:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not enabled the [annotated MVC configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config)

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Ex:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="..." />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

EDIT:
it was a problem with the classpath of the application as it turned out in the below comments

Comment: where do I add it? tried to add it to springapp-servlet.xml in the beginning...org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.

Comment: You need to add `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd` as shown

Comment: Same problem as in the begining...WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'

Comment: do not hit this `http://localhost:8080/spring/hello`, But hit this: `http://localhost:8080/hello` You did not put `spring` word in servlet mapping in`web.xml` file, so exclude spring word from url

Comment: why would I hit http://localhost:8080/hello if my context path for this app is set up for "/spring" in tomcat...tried it just in case doesn't work

Comment: Can you create a empty constructor in the controller class and add a logging statement to it to check whether the controller class is loaded?

Comment: Good call..its not being loaded..?!?!?

Comment: Can you make sure that the controller file is present in the classpath

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be a stupid mistake..my class output directory was on the same level as WEB-INF and not inside it..thank you

Comment: Btw <mvc-annotation-driven /> not necessary as it seems? in 3.2? I'm brand new to spring..